# Handle input and output with shared service

Tags: angular, typescript

I am refactoring code that has a lot of duplicated methods between 2 components. Component A is child of component B, both can be different instances and actually they should. My problem is, that inside some methods I am emitting data and when I try to get the inputs after passing the methods to a service I can't pass the to the template dunno why.

I have something like this at the moment:

component A and component B are emitting events and i didn't changed those methods because i can't separate that logic, how can i make changes to inputs in the service side and get the changes on the component? any help with that?

```
component A 

export class CompA{
 template: ...
 ...
 inputs [
  'value1'
  'value2'
 ]
 outputs: [
 'doSomething'
 'doSomething2'
 'doSomething3'
 ] 

 public value1: string;
 public value2: string

 addLine(){
 //simple example
  if(this.value1 == ""){
   this.doSomething1.emit(3)

  // the functions are obviously bigger but i need this emit inside the service and catch the event in the component
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this question and perhaps add some code? Really having a hard time understanding what you're asking.

Comment: basicly i need to know how to pass some inputs this way Service -> componentA, if i pass the logic to the service the inputs that i need in the component are in the service either, how can i get the data, for example i tried to initialize the data in ngOnInit but it doesn't listen to changes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Maybe building a plunker that demonstrates the issue would be helpful here.

In general, if you need to update data in a service, just set the values.

For example:

**Service**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ShareService {
   public data: string;

   setData(newdata : string){
       this.data = newdata;
   }

   clearData(){
       this.data = '';
   }
}
```

**Component that sets the value**

```
export class PageA {
    constructor(private shareService: ShareService, private router: Router){
    }
    gotoPageB(){
        this.shareService.setData("Sample data");
        this.router.navigate(['pageb']);  
    }

}
```

**Component that gets the value**

```
export class PageB {
    constructor(private shareService: ShareService){ }

    get somedata() : string {
      return this.shareService.data;
    }
}
```

The key here is to use a getter property in the component that gets the value (PageB in this example) so it is updated any time that the data service value changes.

Is this at all close to what you are asking?